# NiFi 1.10 Parameters: How to get them to work?

Tags: apache-nifi

We are running NiFi 1.10 and have defined a Parameter Context. This has been assigned to a Processor Group, and a ListFTP processor has been added to our flow. In the parameter context, there is a parameter called ftp.password, which is set as a sensitive parameter and the password as its value. Then in the ListFTP processor, this parameter is referenced by #{ftp.password}. However, it does not seems to work as it seems to be unable to resolve the parameter. It fails to login to the FTP server, but if I put the password directly into the password field, omitting the use of a parameter value, it works.

Apart from these steps, is there anything else that needs to be done?

1. Creating Parameter Context.
2. Assigning Parameter Context to Processor Group.
3. Creating a Parameter (ftp.password), sensitive is checked.
4. Assigning Parameter to ListFTP's Password field: #{ftp.password}

P.S. Followed this document: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#parameter-contexts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed. Devs are investigated about this and found the logic for some processors are different. See [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6868). I think you already [report](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/nifi-users/201911.mbox/browser) this and got the reason for what is wrong.

It will be fixed in the next version.